# Amending canonical url with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo

I have a canonical url which is seo friendly, however when going to this page there are a redirect in place. I am having issues with Google Plus because of this. If I add the following to the end of the url ?geoip=noredirect it works fine but don't want to change the actual url that the robots search.

If I make this change with JS/JQuery after the page has loaded, will it have an impact on SEO?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the code implemented? Maybe give an example page?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are making your website over-complicated and will be causing problems.

You need to simply.

> I have a canonical url which is seo friendly, however when going to this page there are a redirect in place.

GEO IP redirects cause problems with SEO - ie Google will always be redirected to USA because of server location.

Instead I would recommend just updating a small part of the page based on GEO IP, not redirecting users.